# Doubts regarding the preservation of Quran

Tags: quran, preservation

A question has been already asked here regarding the ways that how Qur'an was transmitted and how it was preserved. But my question is different.

I was reading some Q-A on our sister SE sites and came across this : [Has the Quran preserved since Muhammad ?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/17107/67267)

The top answer concluded that it can't be said surely and hence **NO** . It mentioned some hadiths to support too. How do muslim scholars explain these ?

P.S.: I understand that proving the authenticity of an answer on any other SE site sentence by sentence is not a great thing to do. However, since the preservation of Quran is unanimously believed to be the greatest living miracle by muslims and central to Islam, I can't resist to ask. Thanks, I hope for an answer clearing all doubts.! If you think that this question can be edited and made be better , please feel free to edit it.

Comment: You could have bountied on the given question asking for a more adequate answer instead of re-asking the same question. But since you've asked it here I suppose you want the Muslim perspective then I'd like to ask you to take some time re-formulate a concise question that fits to islamSE! Further did you check the site whether we have some any similar question? I would suggest you to check and then formulate a question with your concerns explaining what is missing from your perspective!

Comment: Related questions: [A question on the preservation of the quran](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/73129/a-question-on-the-preservation-of-the-quran), [Is the quran really preserved or are there missing parts?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35426/is-the-quran-really-preserved-or-are-there-missing-parts-of-the-quran?), [Can we demonstrate that the quran is perfectly preserved?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36210/can-we-demonstrate-that-the-quran-is-perfectly-preserved) and [This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/69804/is-the-qur-an-perfectly-preserved)

Comment: @Medi1Saif Thanks sir. Sir, can I edit my question title and question body ? The edited question will not be the same as I asked but it will be very closely related to what I asked.

Comment: First we are all users on the same level here so no need for the "sir"! Since nobody delivered an answer you are free to edit as you like. Otherwise we mods or community  need to interfere.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Okay thanks. Nevertheless, I called "sir" in only humbleness .